# jolt transform for filtering arrays based on certain criteria

Tags: jolt

There will be multiple SHIFT operations in the spec file, each SHIFT operation is a transformation.
In First SHIFT Operation you will change at the "KeyContactEquivalentBObj", here for each
"AdminSystemValue", you will create a new array if there is no array already created for doing the filtration, Same thing should. In the next SHIFT Operation, you will read the new array added in top, then filter based on the Start date
and End Date, into another new arrays, respectively.
Next SHIFT performs to read the new two filter's arrays and if they have start date then ignore other End Dates array.
After this you have create a new SHIFT layer to filter on the start date array's if you have more than one
by lastUpdatedTimeStamp, (if it is too much you can also perform this in JAVA based on the time constraint).
ง Note: You must perform this in both User related KeyContactEquivalentBObj and in the array of COMPANY related
"KeyPartyRelationshipBObj": ---> "KeyContactEquivalentBObj"

this is the input json
[
{
"operation": "shift",
"spec": {
"TCRMService": {
"ResponseControl": {
"DWLControl": {
"availableResultsCount": "ResultCount"
}
},
"TxResponse": {
"TxResult": {
"ResultCode": "ResultCode",
"DWLError": {
"ErrorMessage": "ErrorMessage",
"availableResultsCount": "ResultCount"
}
},
"ResponseObject": {
"KeyPartySearchResultBObj": {
"*": {
"KeyPartyBobj": {
"*": {
"PartyType": "data[&1].partyType",
"MDMID": "data[&1].userMdmId",
"KeyOrganizationNameObj": {
"*": {
"OrganisationName": "data[&3].companyName"
}
},
"KeyPersonNameBobj": {
"*": {
"FirstName": "data[&3].userFirstName",
"LastName": "data[&3].userLastName",
"MiddleName": "data[&3].userMiddleName"
}
},
"KeyContactEquivalentBObj": {
"*": {
"@(4,AdminSystemValue)": "data[&8].userAdminSystemValues[]",
"@(4,userAdminSystemValues)": {
"@(2,AdminPartyId)": "data[&8].userAdminPartyIds[]",
"@(2,StartDate)": "data[&8].userAdminStartDates[]"
}
}
},
"KeyPartyRelationshipBobj": {
"*": {
"RelationshipType": "data[&3].kbbouserType",
"KeyToPartyBobj": {
"*": {
"KeyPartyBobj": {
"*": {
"DisplayName": "data[&7].userCompanies.[&5].companyName",
"ClientStatusValue": {
"In-Active": {
"#Inactive": "data[&9].userCompanies.[&7].companyStatus"
},
"*": {
"@(2,ClientStatusValue)": "data[&9].userCompanies.[&9].companyStatus"
}
},
"KeyContactEquivalentBObj": {
"*": {
"*": {
"@(4,AdminSystemValue)": "data[&8].userCompanies.[&7].userAdminSystemValues[]",
"@(2,AdminPartyId)": "data[&8].userCompanies.[&7].userAdminPartyIds[]",
"@(2,StartDate)": "data[&8].userCompanies.[&7].userAdminStartDates[]"
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
},
"keyPartyValueBobj": {
"*": {
"SourceIdentValue": {
"KBBO_CIN": {
"@(2,Attribute1String)": "data[&5].kbboEnrollmentStatus"
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
]

i tried this spec but didnot work.

[
{
"operation": "shift",
"spec": {
"TCRMService": {
"ResponseControl": {
"DWLControl": {
"availableResultsCount": "ResultCount"
}
},
"TxResponse": {
"TxResult": {
"ResultCode": "ResultCode",
"DWLError": {
"ErrorMessage": "ErrorMessage",
"availableResultsCount": "ResultCount"
}
},
"ResponseObject": {
"KeyPartySearchResultBObj": {
"*": {
"KeyPartyBobj": {
"*": {
"PartyType": "data[&1].partyType",
"MDMID": "data[&1].userMdmId",
"KeyOrganizationNameObj": {
"*": {
"OrganisationName": "data[&3].companyName"
}
},
"KeyPersonNameBobj": {
"*": {
"FirstName": "data[&3].userFirstName",
"LastName": "data[&3].userLastName",
"MiddleName": "data[&3].userMiddleName"
}
},
"KeyContactEquivalentBObj": {
"*": {
"@(4,AdminSystemValue)": "data[&8].userAdminSystemValues[]",
"@(4,userAdminSystemValues)": {
"@(2,AdminPartyId)": "data[&8].userAdminPartyIds[]",
"@(2,StartDate)": "data[&8].userAdminStartDates[]"
}
}
},
"KeyPartyRelationshipBobj": {
"*": {
"RelationshipType": "data[&3].kbbouserType",
"KeyToPartyBobj": {
"*": {
"KeyPartyBobj": {
"*": {
"DisplayName": "data[&7].userCompanies.[&5].companyName",
"ClientStatusValue": {
"In-Active": {
"#Inactive": "data[&9].userCompanies.[&7].companyStatus"
},
"*": {
"@(2,ClientStatusValue)": "data[&9].userCompanies.[&9].companyStatus"
}
},
"KeyContactEquivalentBObj": {
"*": {
"*": {
"@(4,AdminSystemValue)": "data[&8].userCompanies.

"@(2,AdminPartyId)": "data[&8].userCompanies.
"@(2,StartDate)": "data[&8].userCompanies.[&7].userAdminStartDates[]"
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
},
"keyPartyValueBobj": {
"*": {
"SourceIdentValue": {
"KBBO_CIN": {
"@(2,Attribute1String)": "data[&5].kbboEnrollmentStatus"
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
]